# Json object not found exception

Tags: java, json

I am new to this field and i have no idea where am i going wrong.

```
org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException: JSONObject["State load X2\/SETTINGS\/SETTINGS.XML"] not found.
    at org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:360)
    at com.comcast.xre.testframework.services.TestModuleDataClient.convertJSON2String(TestModuleDataClient.java:258)
    at com.comcast.xre.testframework.services.TestModuleDataClient.hashGet(TestModuleDataClient.java:112)
    at com.comcast.xre.testframework.util.X1ToolkitActions.getAppTimerValue(X1ToolkitActions.java:417)
    at com.comcast.xre.testframework.util.X1ToolkitActions.waitForAppTimerValueChange(X1ToolkitActions.java:527)
    at com.comcast.guide.actionhandlers.X1GuideBaseTestActions.enterSettingsScreenAndSelectDesiredSetting(X1GuideBaseTestActions.java:838)
    at com.comcast.guide.actionhandlers.ParentalControlSettingsAction.setPurchasePIN(ParentalControlSettingsAction.java:635)
    at com.comcast.guide.functests.ParentalControlTest.purchasePINTest(ParentalControlTest.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.InvokeMethodRunnable.runOne(InvokeMethodRunnable.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.InvokeMethodRunnable.run(InvokeMethodRunnable.java:37)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: going to need a little more context.

Comment: Hi Anonym, please click the [edit] button and add in the JSON you are trying to parse, my initial thought is that you have an incorrectly formatted JSON object. Could you also provide the code you are running that throws this exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first suggestion would be to surround your code with a try-catch block to catch the exception.  I would also suggest using the JSONObject.has method to see if this file exists.

See http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#has(java.lang.String) for more info.